# C# txt contains X instead of txt's line contains X

Tags: c#

I just started C#. Also, my native language is not English, so I will use Google Translate. I want login to my app with password. On the other hand, when passwords are stored as .txt on an internet and tried to be entered into the application, I want it to check whether the value entered in the textbox is in a line of the .txt stored on the internet. But when I try as follows, for example, even when I type a in the textbox, the transition is successful because the .txt contains the letter a. How can I make the program check if the value written to the textbox is the same as a line in the .txt? (i know its easy to crack, only for learning)

```
        string USERIDLIST = wb.DownloadString(".../userID.txt");
        if (USERIDLIST.Contains(textBox6.Text))
        {
            // Make login
        }
```

Comment: `if (USERIDLIST == textBox6.Text)`

Comment: You need to read the text file as lines, and then compare each line according to your needs. See duplicate.